# GCMBroadcastreceiver onRecive not receiving messages but something strange on Android 4.2.2

Tags: android, push-notification, broadcastreceiver, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to make an app combining with **GCM+PHP+MYSQL**.
My app can get registration Id from Google Server and store it to my sever, but **onReceive()** method seems not working properly when I send messages to device(genymotion Htc One 4.2.2 with google API17).

**The echo form my server shows:**

```
{"multicast_id":6654020603006207086,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1383807091667423%6852480ef9fd7ecd"}]}
```

So I think server part may works fine.

**The apps got below notification before I sent message:**

```
Recieved:Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=48]
```

But the message form server disappeared, nothing happened in onRecive(...) .

I've read servel topics here but I still cant figure out why.

I just implement Broadcastreceiver without GCMIntentService becasue some references do this easier than google's reference.

This question bother me for 2 days, plz help me m(_ _)m ..

**Here is my Manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.csie.gcmtest"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<permission android:name="com.csie.gcmtest.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature"></permission>
<uses-permission android:name="com.csie.gcmtest.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.csie.gcmtest.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.csie.gcmtest" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>

</manifest>
```

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
String SENDER_ID = "327943842431";  //project ID
Context context;
String strRegId;
TextView tvRegisterMsg;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tvRegisterMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRegisterMsg);
    context = getApplicationContext();

    // initial GCM
    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);

    // register with Google.
    new AsyncTask<Void,String,String>() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String msg = "";
                try {
                    if (gcm == null) {
                        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                    }
                    strRegId = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
                    msg = "Device registered, registration id=" + strRegId;

                    // send id to our server
                    sendRegIdToServer(strRegId);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                        msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
                    }
            return msg;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
            tvRegisterMsg.append(msg + "\n");
        }

    }.execute(null, null, null);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

private void sendRegIdToServer(final String strId) {
    new AsyncTask<Void,String,String>() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String strResponseCode = "";
            HttpPost httpRequest = new HttpPost("http://89.0.1.213/android_add.php");
            List<NameValuePair> p = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            p.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", strId));
            try {
                /* 發出HTTP request */

                httpRequest.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(p, HTTP.UTF_8));

                /* 取得HTTP response */

                HttpResponse httpResponse = new DefaultHttpClient().execute(httpRequest);

                strResponseCode = Integer.toString(httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            return strResponseCode;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
            tvRegisterMsg.append("status code:  " + msg + "\n");
        }

     }.execute(null, null, null);
}
}
```

**Broadcastreceiver:**

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
 static final String TAG = "GCMDemo";
 public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
 private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
 NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
 Context ctx;

 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  Log.i("onReceive","fuck");

  GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
  ctx = context;

  String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);
  if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
   sendNotification("Send error: " + intent.getExtras().toString());
   Log.i("onReceive","fuck_type_error");
  } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED .equals(messageType)) {
   sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " + intent.getExtras().toString());
   Log.i("onReceive","deleted");
  } else {
   sendNotification("Received: " + intent.getExtras().toString());
   Log.i("onReceive","received:"+ intent.getExtras().toString());
  }
  setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
   Log.i("onReceive","fuck done");
 }

 // Put the GCM message into a notification and post it.
 private void sendNotification(String msg) {
  mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

  PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0,
    new Intent(ctx, MainActivity.class), 0);

  NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setContentTitle("GCM Notification")
    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
    .setContentText(msg);

  mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
  mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
 }
}
```